# Accessibility issues with updated design

Tags: bug, design

Firstly - congrats on the site launch! I love the clean style of it and soft colour scheme. However, this has raised some issues. Namely; most of the text fails accessibility colour contrast ratios.

Basically, almost all the text on screen except the unvisited question title link itself is of too low a contrast.

For example I ran the site through the [webaim WAVE accessibility checker](http://wave.webaim.org/report#/http%3A%2F%2Fgraphicdesign.stackexchange.com%2F) and the contrast option shows as per below screenshot:

[image]

So yes. Nice overall style, congrats on the launch, but I think it'd be better if you could make it a bit more accessible. Boring, I know. But still.

Comment: This is a very valid point. Even absent this, several folks have noted hover states and status indications that are so subtle as to be almost undetectable.